# Slicing twice in Python

Tags: python, performance, slice

Often times I have an offset and length of data I want to extract from a str or bytes.

The way I most often see it done is:

```
mystr[ offset: offset+length ]
```

How much less efficient is it to do the following instead (which seems clearer to understand)?

```
mystr[ offset: ][ :length ]
```

If the data were actually copied both times, and memory allocated for each copy, this would be terribly less efficient.  But if it is done with pointers and reference count magic, maybe not so much less efficient?  It could even be optimized.

This also begs the question of the efficiency of longer compositions of slice operations, although I haven't found the need for more, so far.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a copy is made each time.

Comment: Why on earth would you even think of that?  Yes, it's going to create a useless internediate list.  You just need to learn to read Python slices as first/last and don't think of it as "length".

Comment: @TimRoberts Why? Because offset length pair is often the input to a procedure.  I know how Python slice is defined, just not how it is implemented/optimized.  And it sounds like this isn't optimized.... but it could be.

Comment: It depends on what `mystr` is. The slicing operation is defined by the `__getitem__` method: if you define this method on a class you can have your custom behaviour (e.g. such that `mystr[offset:]` returns a view into `mystr`, and not a copy).

Comment: @Amadan Interesting point, and since both bytes and str are immutable, it seems like there shouldn't be a need for a copy, just some pointer and refcount magic.  But of course, I can't write __gettitem__ for str or bytes.

Comment: You mention bytes-  note that if you use a `memoryview` object, you can slice **without** making a copy, meaning the overhead minimal. The constraint being it then only works on bytes. [Docs page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview)

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR**

> The longer the string, the more `mystr[ offset: ][ :length ]` sucks
> when compared to `mystr[ offset: offset+length ]`

**Background:**

You can `timeit` if you like and the results are dramatic (at least for vanilla python and the complete works of Shakespeare). `mystr[ offset: offset+length ]` is several orders of magnitude faster than `mystr[ offset: ][ :length ]`.

```py
import timeit

setup = """
offset = 1000
length = 1000
with open("shakespeare.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file_in:
    mystr = file_in.read()

def test1(mystr):
    return mystr[ offset: offset+length ]

def test2(mystr):
    return mystr[ offset: ][ :length ]
"""

print(f"Test1: {timeit.timeit('test1(mystr)', setup=setup, number=1000)}")
print(f"Test2: {timeit.timeit('test2(mystr)', setup=setup, number=1000)}")
```

On my laptop with the complete works of Shakespeare I get results like:

```
Test1: 0.00045
Test2: 2.98909
```

Note that the text in question is fairly long and with a shorter text the results are not quite as bad.

```py
import timeit

setup = """
offset = 1000
length = 1000
with open("shakespeare.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file_in:
    mystr = file_in.read()[:3000]

def test1(mystr):
    return mystr[ offset: offset+length ]

def test2(mystr):
    return mystr[ offset: ][ :length ]
"""

print(f"Test1: {timeit.timeit('test1(mystr)', setup=setup, number=1000)}")
print(f"Test2: {timeit.timeit('test2(mystr)', setup=setup, number=1000)}")
```

With that shorter string I get:

```
Test1: 0.00045
Test2: 0.00081
```

Note that the timing of `test1()` did not vary by the length of the text, while the longer the text is, the dramatically slower `test2()` becomes.

Comment: Thanks for the benchmark. Of course, you chose a mystr value that is huge to exacurbate overhead if copies, but that is the point of such a benchmark.  As noted in the comments on the question, str and bytes are immutable, so it doesn't seem like the copy should be necessary, although when the source mystr is so huge, there is obviously a space win if it can be discarded after the extraction.